# How do I transfer Mapping code from Entity Framework to Entity Worker Core?

Tags: entity-framework

The original code is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity&#60;OriginalClass&#62;().Map&#60;OtherClass&#62;(x => x.Requires("Field1").HasValue("Value1"));
```

It doesn't compile and I can't seem to find the equivalent code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance

My code for core will be something like this

modelBuilder.Entity<OriginalClass>().HasDiscriminator<string>("Field1").HasValue<OtherClass>("Value1").HasValue<OtherClass2>("Value2");

Comment: Read the documentation https://github.com/AlenToma/EntityWorker.Core/blob/master/Documentation/Repository.md

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could translate it to entityworker

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OtherClass>().
HasNotNullable(x => x.Field1).
HasDefaultOnEmpty(x=> x.Field1, "the field is empty"));
```

read Attribute section 
https://github.com/AlenToma/EntityWorker.Core/blob/master/Documentation/Attributes.md